# Ошибка при написания бота для телеграм

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Ошибка:

```
$ C:/Users/sorre/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/Python/IlyaSamaelLondony1Bot/main.py
2021-09-22 20:49:37,567 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:49:37,899 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:49:38,461 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:49:39,535 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:49:41,605 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:49:45,676 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:49:53,749 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:50:09,815 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2021-09-22 20:50:41,880 (__init__.py:653 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
```

Код:

````
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет "  + message.from_user.first_name + ' ' +message.from_user.last_name + ", я бот!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная **ошибка** выдается при авторизации (когда **токен** указан неверно - попробуйте проверить все ли вы указали корректно)

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
```